# Treating data as categorical in linear regression

Tags: python, pandas, linear-regression, categorical-data

I have data in a `csv` file that looks somewhat like this:

```
column1    column2
   b          2
   c          4
   z          1
   g          3
...
```

(This is not the real data) `Column1` is categorical and `column2` is continuous and I want to carry out linear regression on this data. My code looks like this at the moment:

```
# Function to get data from the csv file.
def import_data(file_name):
 df = pd.read_csv(file_name).drop_duplicates()
 X_parameter = []
 Y_parameter = []
 for alpha, beta in zip(df['column1'], df['column2']):
       X_parameter.append([float(alpha)])
       Y_parameter.append(float(beta))
 return X_parameter, Y_parameter


X, Y = import_data(filename)
def linear_model_main(X_parameters, Y_parameters, predict_value):

 # Create linear regression object

 regress = linear_model.LinearRegression()
 regress.fit(X_parameters, Y_parameters)
 prediction_outcome = regress.predict(predict_value)
 predictions = {}
 predictions['intercept'] = regress.intercept_
 predictions['coefficient'] = regress.coef_
 predictions['predicted_value'] = prediction_outcome
 return predictions
```

I'm not sure how to specify in this code that `column1` is categorical? I tried changing it to numerical data (`a = 1, b = 2, ...`) but Python is treating it as continuous.

Comment: `float(alpha)` doesn't raise an error?

Comment: Maybe try binarizing your data first. Thinking about how LR works, this approach seems to make sense. http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.LabelBinarizer.html Is there a particular reason you won't use something like RandomForestRegressor, which I believe can handle categorical data directly?

Comment: Take a look at [OneHotEncoding](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/preprocessing.html#encoding-categorical-features)

Comment: @DavidZemens it does when I use the `column` data as it is without converting it into numerical form.

Comment: If you must convert it to a numerical form, then use `int` instead of `float`?

Comment: @DavidZemens it still won't treat the data as categorical though

Comment: Without being able to test this code directly I don't know what you mean by "it won't treat the data as categorical" (I know what categorical or discrete data is, and how it differs from continuous datas, I just don't know what you mean by that statement)

Comment: `pd.get_dummies()` to explicitly create dummy variables.  `.astype('category')` will convert a column to categorical (a good idea here) but depending on the regression package, you'll probably still need to create explicit dummies.  `pd.get_dummies` ought to suffice for any regression package though.

Comment: @DavidZemens I mean that even if I use `int` instead of `float`, the original problem of converting `column1` into binary categorical data is not solved

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`get_dummies`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.get_dummies.html) to return them as dummy variables

```
>>> pd.concat([df, pd.get_dummies(df.column1)], axis=1)
  column1  column2  b  c  g  z
0       b        2  1  0  0  0
1       c        4  0  1  0  0
2       z        1  0  0  0  1
3       g        3  0  0  1  0
```

EDIT:

```
del df['column1']
df = df[['b', 'c', 'g', 'z', 'column2']]
>>> df
   b  c  g  z  column2
0  1  0  0  0        2
1  0  1  0  0        4
2  0  0  0  1        1
3  0  0  1  0        3

regress.fit(df.iloc[:, :-1].values, df.iloc[:, -1].values)
```

Comment: this worked well in converting the data to a binary form but how do I use it in regression? When I call the `linear_model_main` object by doing `result = linear_model_main(X, Y, predictionvalue)`, I'm getting an error that says `y = y.astype(np.float64)
ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.`

Comment: it is not working really. I'm getting an error saying `raise KeyError('%s not in index' % objarr[mask])
KeyError: "['b' 'c' 'g' 'z' 'column2'] not in index"`.